# Issue with getting background color from a cell in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to get a background color from a cell in an excel sheet using [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel).
Actually the background color is #FFFFFF and font color is #000000 that means there is no fill or font color added to the cell, but i'm getting the background color as 000000 and font color as 000000.
This is my excel which i'm reading.
[image]
This is the code which i'm trying to get the bgcolor and fontcolor:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$row)->getFill()->getStartColor()->getRGB();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A'.$row)->getFill()->getEndColor()->getRGB();
```

What i'm doing wrong here. Anyone please.

Comment: how you set the colors?

Comment: Is there a conditional style for the cell?

Comment: @MarkBaker actually i'm reading an excel which have styles.

Comment: I gathered that, I do know a little bit about Excel and about PHPExcel.... but the background colour could be applied by a conditional style, based on the value in the cell

Comment: but the background colour could be applied by a conditional style?? how

Comment: the first column product id gives me the correct colors. but the cells under it 1, 2, 3 values gives bgcolor as 000000 and fontcolor as 000000

Comment: [How Background colour of a cell can be changed using conditional formatting](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/conditional-formatting.html)... I don't know what your spreadsheet contains, so all I can do is guess why background colour might be different, conditional formatting is a possibility

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154660/discussion-between-rahul-and-mark-baker).

Comment: @MarkBaker Does this question don't have an answer?? Its a simple question i have posted on SO. How to get the background color of a cell if at its there.

Comment: Please note that I am not available 24x7x365 to provide free support for PHPExcel.... I do have a real job that I need to work at.... I try to support PHPExcel when I am able

Comment: @MarkBaker Still we all appreciate the time you have dedicated to the library. Thanks for your support.

Comment: You can send me a copy, and I'll try and identify what the problem is; but just as a check, you haven't loaded the file using readDataOnly set to true?

Comment: @MarkBaker yes i didn't do that. how we can set that readDataOnly to true.

Comment: You ___don't___ want to set readDataOnly to true, because that tells PHPExcel to load only the data and none of the style information... but a lot of people do use it because it saves memory, and then wonder why styles aren't loaded